# byte[] does not contain a definition for concat

Tags: c#, cryptography, asp.net-core-mvc, hmacsha1, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm attempting to generate a HMAC-SHA1 in my .Net Core application using the answer found to this question:

[generate HMAC-SHA1 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931840/generate-hmac-sha1-in-c-sharp)

However, I am getting an error of `byte[] does not contain a defintion for Concat`. I've tried searching around on here and I haven't seem to come across an answer.

This error occurs at the line `var key2 = key1.Concat(oauth_consumer_secret).ToArray();`

```
using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
{
    var encodedStringAsByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedString);

    var key1 = sha1.ComputeHash(encodedStringAsByte);
    var key2 = key1.Concat(oauth_consumer_secret).ToArray();
    var key3 = sha1.ComputeHash(key2);

    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(key3);
 }
```

Any insight and knowledge is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `oauth_consumer_secret`?

Comment: I don't know asp net core or whatever this is, but high level languages usually overload '+' to mean string/buffer concatenation... if that doesn't work you probably need a bigger buffer and copy them both in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oauth_consumer_secret` needs to be a `byte[]` and you appear to be trying to pass a `string` in. You should do this instead:

```
//snip
var encodedSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oauth_consumer_secret);
var key2 = key1.Concat(encodedSecret).ToArray();
//snip
```

Comment: Ah of course, `oauth_consumer_secret` was a string. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you're just missing the assembly include

```
using System.Linq;
```